# JavaScript data-toogle

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table in html and want to replace that table with another table when a button is pressed and again back to first table when second button is pressed. i tried this roughly in a html file and it is working but when same logic i applied in my django project to toggle table data it is not working. Below is the JS ansd CSS code.

**CSS**

```
    table.hidden {
      display: none;
    }
```

**JavaScript**

```
    document.getElementById("b1").addEventListener("click", function() {
      document.getElementById("01").innerHTML = document.getElementById(
        "02"
      ).innerHTML;
    });
    document.getElementById("b2").addEventListener("click", function() {
      document.getElementById("01").innerHTML = document.getElementById(
        "03"
      ).innerHTML;
    });
```

The html table and buttons code is as follows

```
<button id="b1" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-xs mb-2 ml-5" style="font-size: 0.8em;">Daily Sale </button>
<button id="b2" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-xs mb-2 ml-2" style="font-size: 0.8em;">Monthly</button>

  <table id="01" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-sm ml-auto css-serial">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">S.no.</th>
        <th scope="col">Customer</th>
        <th scope="col">Quantity (MT)</th>
        <th scope="col">Bulkers</th>
      </tr>   
    </thead>
    <tbody>
{% for x,y,z in sum_list %} 
      <tr>
        <td scope="row"></td>
        <td>{{x}}</td>
        <td>{{y}}</td>
        <td>{{z}}</td>
      </tr>
{% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <table id="02" class="hidden table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-sm ml-auto css-serial">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
      <th scope="col">S.no.</th>
      <th scope="col">Customer</th>
      <th scope="col">Quantity (MT)</th>
      <th scope="col">Bulkers</th>
    </tr>   
    </thead>
  <tbody>
{% for x,y,z in sum_list %} 
    <tr>
      <td scope="row"></td>
      <td>{{x}}</td>
      <td>{{y}}</td>
      <td>{{z}}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>


  <table id="03" class="hidden table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-sm ml-auto css-serial">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">S.no.</th>
        <th scope="col">ABC</th>
        <th scope="col">XYZ</th>
        <th scope="col">ASD</th>
      </tr>   
    </thead>
    <tbody>
{% for x,y,z in month_sum %}
      <tr>
        <td scope="row"></td>
        <td>{{x}}</td>
        <td>{{y}}</td>
        <td>{{z}}</td>
      </tr>
{% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

The table with id 01 will be default table and will be visible when page is load. The table with id 02 will be shown when button with id b1 is pressed and table with id 03 with button having id b2. please help me solving this.

Comment: it is more easy if you have a parent element (like a DIV) for all your tables

Comment: Actually I have not pasted the full code. This table is in a div element. could you please tell me how it will be done.

Comment: There is a closing div element in the code, without an opening tag by the way. I tried your code and it seems to be working, not sure what the problem is, see below the snippet. Anyways I also think it's a strange way to replace the table's HTML content. Just show / hide them via their parent div. There is no need for the third table at all.

Comment: Please read this : https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  we don't care an dislike to read hundred lines of code for just 1 algorithmic question!

Comment: This a bad idea to copy a HTML content into another. just use `css display:none` for those you want to hide.

Comment: Ok i will follow this suggestion.

Comment: My answer below is a sample code to illustrate this, did you see it?

Comment: @LovepreetSingh Are you using bootstrap framework? if yes then don't need to write single line of JS code for hide/show table as depend on button click. You can use Bootstrap **Tab** or **Collapse** Functionality with help of Bootstrap data-* attributes. So  this technique to solve your issue by only Two tables so no need to create 3 tables. Doc: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#tabs

Answer (score 0):

Here's your original code, just removed the spare `</div>` tag, it seems to be working though. Can you tell what the problem is? As mentioned in my comment above, showing and hiding DIV tags would be a far better approach, without the need of the redundant third table.

```js
document.getElementById("b1").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("01").innerHTML = document.getElementById(
    "02"
  ).innerHTML;
});
document.getElementById("b2").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("01").innerHTML = document.getElementById(
    "03"
  ).innerHTML;
});
```

```css
table.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<button id="b1" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-xs mb-2 ml-5" style="font-size: 0.8em;">Daily Sale </button>
<button id="b2" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-xs mb-2 ml-2" style="font-size: 0.8em;">Monthly</button>

<table id="01" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-sm ml-auto css-serial">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">S.no.</th>
      <th scope="col">Customer</th>
      <th scope="col">Quantity (MT)</th>
      <th scope="col">Bulkers</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td scope="row">1</td>
      <td>{{x}}</td>
      <td>{{y}}</td>
      <td>{{z}}</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td scope="row">2</td>
      <td>{{x}}</td>
      <td>{{y}}</td>
      <td>{{z}}</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>

<table id="02" class="hidden table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-sm ml-auto css-serial">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">S.no.</th>
      <th scope="col">Customer</th>
      <th scope="col">Quantity (MT)</th>
      <th scope="col">Bulkers</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td scope="row">1</td>
      <td>{{x}}</td>
      <td>{{y}}</td>
      <td>{{z}}</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td scope="row">2</td>
      <td>{{x}}</td>
      <td>{{y}}</td>
      <td>{{z}}</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>

<table id="03" class="hidden table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-sm ml-auto css-serial">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">S.no.</th>
      <th scope="col">ABC</th>
      <th scope="col">XYZ</th>
      <th scope="col">ASD</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row">1</td>
      <td>{{x}}</td>
      <td>{{y}}</td>
      <td>{{z}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row">2</td>
      <td>{{x}}</td>
      <td>{{y}}</td>
      <td>{{z}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: From Bootstrap4 to removed `btn-xs` class. Follow: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/migration/#buttons

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple code to show you "my" method to do this

```js
const btChangeTable = document.getElementById('bt-Change-Table')
  ,   AllTableDiv   = document.getElementById('All-tables')
  ,   TableActiv    = { current:0, classList: [ 'table1', 'table2', 'table3' ] }
  ;
btChangeTable.onclick = () =>
  {
  TableActiv.current = ++TableActiv.current % TableActiv.classList.length
  AllTableDiv.className = TableActiv.classList[ TableActiv.current ]
  }
```

```css
table {
  margin          : 1em;
  border-collapse : collapse;
  font-family     : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size       : 14px;
  }
td { 
  border           : 1px solid gray;
  text-align       : center;
  padding          : .7em 0;
  width            : 2em;
  } 

#All-tables.table1 > #Table-2,
#All-tables.table1 > #Table-3 { display : none }

#All-tables.table2 > #Table-1,
#All-tables.table2 > #Table-3 { display : none }

#All-tables.table3 > #Table-1,
#All-tables.table3 > #Table-2 { display : none }
```

```html
<button id="bt-Change-Table">Change Table view</button>

<div id="All-tables" class="table1">
  <table id="Table-1">
    <caption> table 1 - Daily Sale  </caption>
    <tbody>
      <tr> <td>a</td> <td>b</td> <td>c</td> <td>d</td> </tr>
      <tr> <td>e</td> <td>f</td> <td>g</td> <td>h</td> </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table id="Table-2">
    <caption> table 2 - Monthly Sale </caption>
    <tbody>
      <tr> <td>i</td> <td>j</td> <td>k</td> <td>l</td> </tr>
      <tr> <td>m</td> <td>n</td> <td>o</td> <td>p</td> </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table id="Table-3">
    <caption> table 3 - Year Sale  </caption>
    <tbody>
      <tr> <td>a</td> <td>b</td> <td>c</td> <td>d</td> </tr>
      <tr> <td>m</td> <td>n</td> <td>o</td> <td>p</td> </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```